# GridView: leftMargin and rightMargin properties do not work

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

It **works** okay for the `Flickable` (i.e. `Flickable` with `Grid` and same `Rectangle`s (see code below) in it).

Here's an example for GridView:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ApplicationWindow {
    id: rootWindow

    visible: true
    width: 300
    height: 300

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "yellow"

        GridView {
            id: gridView
            anchors.fill: parent

            cellWidth: 50
            cellHeight: 50
            model: 54

            bottomMargin: 10
            topMargin: 10
            leftMargin: 10 // this doesn't work
            rightMargin: 10 // this doesn't work

            delegate: Rectangle {
                width: gridView.cellWidth - 1
                height: gridView.cellHeight - 1
                color: "green"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like smth weird is going on, indeed - I'd file this at https://bugreports.qt.io and see what they say. GridXXX stuff has quite some issues, I think, so no surprize.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe thats what you are looking for:

```
    ...
    GridView {
        id: gridView
        anchors {
            fill: parent
            margins: 10
        }
        clip: true

        cellWidth: 50
        cellHeight: 50
        model: 54

        delegate: Rectangle {
            width: gridView.cellWidth - 1
            height: gridView.cellHeight - 1
            color: "green"
        }
    }
    ...
```

Comment: This would trim mouse area of the GridView, that is you would not be able to scroll when mouse is over the margins.